# JS дождаться загрузки SPA страницы при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript, spa

У меня есть скрипт, который выполняется на странице вк в консоли браузера. Он парсит некоторые данные с разных страниц.

Основная идея в том, что этот скрипт именно в консоли.

Итак, чтобы перемещаться между страницами я получаю в переменную нужную мне ссылку или кнопку и применяю на нём `.click()`, чтобы перейти на эту страницу без перезагрузки страницы (Тк VK - SPA). И выходит что скрипт продолжает работать в консоли.

Но тут проблема. Вот я "кликнул" на ссылку, и нужно нужно дождаться, пока контент загрузится, чтобы спарсить следующие данные. В данный момент я использую просто таймер+промис, чтобы подождать какое-то время, но это же ненадежный вариант.

Итак, как отследить загрузку такого контента?

Comment: Добавьте [AJAX hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page) и отслеживайте нужные вам данные.

Comment: @nazarpunk я нашел запрос, который загружает нужные мне данные. Но как его отследить? У меня скрипт парсит некоторые данные из ВК. Код, который вы скинули работает, как я понял, для запросов через `XMLHttpRequest`. Я попробовал его в консоли браузера выполнить - в консоль выводятся некоторые запросы, но, к сожалению, нет запроса, который меня интересуют. Вероятно, тот запрос посылается каким-то другим путем

Comment: Попробуйте [fetch hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728723/hook-all-fetch-api-ajax-requests), может vk уже на него перешёл.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вот это, в целом думаю должно решить проблему https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: А вы уверены, что эти события срабатывают, когда человек нажимает на ссылку?

Comment: У меня есть функция, например `toProfile` в ней такой код ` document.querySelector('#l_pr a').click();` как узнать, что имя человека с этой страницы уже загрузилось?